# Count the number of relationship types to add them as a frequency-property to the edges

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to count the different types of relationships in my neo4j graph to add them as a "frequency" property to the corresponding edges (ie I have 4 e:EX relationship types, so I would like my edges of type EX to have an e.frequency=4).

So far I have played around with this code:

```
MATCH ()-[e:EX]-()
WITH e, count(e) as amount  
SET e.frequency = amount
RETURN e
```

For this piece of code my returned e.frequency is 2 for all EX edges. Maybe anyone here knows how to correct this?

Comment: `EX` is a relationship "type", in neo4j terminology. So, "I have 4 e:EX relationship types" does not make sense. Do you mean that you have 4 `EX` relationship instances?  Also, what are you trying to use the `frequency` property for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here is what your query is doing

```
// Match all EX edges (relationships), ignore direction
MATCH ()-[e:EX]-()
// Logical partition; With the edges, count how many times that instance occurred (will always be 2. (a)-[e:EX]->(b) and the reverse order of (b)<-[e:EX]-(a)
WITH e, count(e) as amount
// Set the property frequency on the instance of e to amount (2)
SET e.frequency = amount
// return the edges
RETURN e
```

So to filter the duplicates (reverse direction match), you need to specify the direction on the MATCH. So `MATCH ()-[e:EX]->()`. for the frequency part, you don't even need a match; you can just count the occurences of the pattern `WITH SIZE(()-[:EX]->()) as c` (SIZE because pattern matching returns a list, not a row set)

So

```
WITH SIZE(()-[:EX]->()) as c
MATCH ()-[e:EX]->()
SET e.frequency = c
return e
```

Although, frequency will be invalidated as soon as an EX edge is created or deleted, so I would just open your Cypher with asking for the edge count.

Also, in this trivial case, the best way to get the relation count is with a MATCH - COUNT because this form helps the Cypher planer to recognize that it can just fetch the edge count from it's internal metadata store.

```
MATCH ()-[e:EX]->()
WITH COUNT(e) as c
MATCH ()-[e:EX]->()
SET e.frequency = c
return e
```

Comment: Just a quick addition...Tezra is right, for these trivial cases the Cypher approach (without the proc calls) is easier. Just keep in mind that for it to use the count store, the relationship in the pattern needs a direction, and the count aggregation needs to be the only thing in the WITH or RETURN. More info about usage and limitations of the counts store [in this knowledge base article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/fast-counts-using-the-count-store/)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want this information for quick access later for any node with that type. If you're planning on deleting or adding edges in your graph, you should realize that your data will get stale quickly, and a graph-wide query to update the property on every edge in the graph just doesn't make sense.

Thankfully Neo4j keeps a transactional count store of various statistics, including the number of relationships per relationship type.

It's easiest to get these via procedure calls, either in Neo4j itself or APOC Procedures.

If you have APOC installed, you can see the map of relationship type counts like this:

```
CALL apoc.meta.stats() YIELD relTypesCount
RETURN relTypesCount
```

If you know which type you want the count of, you can use dot notation into the relTypesCount map to get the value in question.

If it's dynamic (either passed in as a parameter, or obtained after matching to a relationship in the query) you can use the map index notation to get the count in question like this:

```
CALL apoc.meta.stats() YIELD relTypesCount
MATCH ()-[r]->()
WITH relTypesCount, r
LIMIT 5
RETURN type(r) as type, relTypesCount[type(r)] as count
```

If you don't have APOC, you can make use of `db.stats.retrieve('GRAPH COUNTS') 
YIELD data`, but you'll have to do some additional filtering to make sure you get the counts for ALL of the relationships of the given type, and exclude the counts that include the labels of the start or end nodes:

```
CALL db.stats.retrieve('GRAPH COUNTS') YIELD data
WITH [entry IN data.relationships WHERE NOT exists(entry.startLabel) AND NOT exists(entry.endLabel)] as relCounts
MATCH ()-[r]->()
WITH relCounts, r
LIMIT 5
RETURN type(r) as type, [rel in relCounts WHERE rel.relationshipType = type(r) | rel.count][0] as count
```